# Is it okay to have the same keys for different list items rendered within separate map functions in the same React component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

**Q:** Is it okay to have the same keys for different list items rendered within separate `map` functions in the same React component?

**Situation:** As you see in the example code, I'm using indices as the `key` identifiers. They both will start from 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on.

Edit {

*(Both `initialMessageData` and `messageData` are dynamic, items getting added over time but guaranteed to be **unique** for each loop itself)*

}

**Code example:**

```
  ...
  ...
  return (
    <ul>
      {initialMessageData.map((data, index) => (
        <ChatLog key={index} data={data} />
      ))}
      {messageData.map((data, index) => (
        <ChatLog key={index} data={data} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```

- If it is okay, why?
- If it is not okay, why?

Comment: Additional thing. It is better not to use the array index as the key. https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From React's docs:

> Keys tell React which array item each component corresponds to, so
> that it can match them up later. This becomes important if your array
> items can move (e.g. due to sorting), get inserted, or get deleted. A
> well-chosen key helps React infer what exactly has happened, and make
> the correct updates to the DOM tree.

And also:

> Keys must be unique among siblings. However, it’s okay to use the same
> keys for JSX nodes in different arrays.

So to answer your question, yes it's ok because the list items come from two separate arrays. [Here](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists) is a link to the docs for further reading